# How to use QString and '\'

Tags: c++, qt

I have a program that using in wichI use getOpenFileName like :

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                    tr("Select video"), "d:\\", tr("Video files (*.avi)"));
strcpy(thePath, fileName.toStdString().c_str()); // static char thePath[66];
scilab.setPathloc(thePath);
```

`scilab` is an object of a class that send jobs to the Program SCILAB.it work like :

```
char std_dev[99];
char direc[60];
sprintf(direc,"direc=\'d:/BMDvideos/%s/%s/\'",getSessionName(),getVideoname());
sprintf(std_dev,"fn=\'d:/BMDvideos/%s/%s/%s.avi\'",
        getSessionName(),getVideoname(),getVideoname());
SendScilabJob(direc);
SendScilabJob(std_dev);
//SendScilabJob("fn=\'d:/BMDvideos/Aufnahme0.avi\'");
SendScilabJob("exec('U:/scilab/done/std_dev.sce');");
```

well this works fine, but when I use the `QString` like:

```
 char text1 [70]    ;
 sprintf(text1,"disp(fn=\'%s\');",getPathloc());
 SendScilabJob("exec('U:/scilab/done/std_dev.sce');");
```

nothing works, I think it because of the `//` that I have to use in `sprintf`. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: In a _string_ literal you don't have to escape the single-quote character `'`.

Comment: what happens to text1 in the second example, and is 70 chars enough?  Why don't you use a std::string or vector<char> instead of a char array? How does SendScilabJob work - is this your own code using QProcess?

Comment: @Pete I already want to do this but SCILAjobs take only char[], yes my code is using QProcess but why does it work in the first part `??

Comment: You can get a `const char*` from a `std::string` using [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). I'm sure `QString` has something similar.

Comment: "but when I use the QString like :" - if `getPathloc()` returns `QString` then it wouldn't work. You should pass `getPathloc().toAscii().constData()' to sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@borisbn almost certainly found the problem. `sprintf` is a C function, not C++, and it's not typesafe at all. It assumes that you know which types to pass. And for `%s`, that's `const char*`.

The simple solution: Don't use `sprintf`. You've got a proper C++ class, `QString`. E.g.  `QString text = QString("disp(fn=\'%1\');").arg(getPathloc())`. Note that you don't use `%s`. Since it's C++, it's typesafe, and the compiler will figure out whether you're passing an integer or a string.